# Why does this matrix calculation goes 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm in trouble with this matrix calculation in python. I have matrix as numpy array`a = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]])` and tried some calculation. But I got the error like

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

So I checked out some steps and turned out matrix calculation went 0.

for instance, I ran this code

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
print(a * np.identity(3))
```

and the result is

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

But the answer is

```
[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you probably meant `a @ np.identity(3)`. `*` is element-wise multiplication. I'm voting to close as a typo, since this is very basic indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Matrix multiplication is done using `@` in Python with `np.array`. With `*` you get the Hadamard product.